# How to enable "initialize and script activex controls not marked as safe for scripting(ActiveXObject)" in IE automatically through js or batch file

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, batch-file, activexobject

According to my requirement I need to implement a **filesystem** using **ActiveXObject** in IE. I implemented the same but difficulty is that to ask users to enable the "initialize and script activex controls not marked as safe for scripting" option manually from **Internet options**. So can anyone please suggest me how to enable the same via coding(Javascript or batch).

Answer (score 0):

NOT An Answer or solution, just some guidance based on brief experience in similar area. IE-11 doesn't allow ActiveX object anyway to be used directly unless IE security settings are lowered as you mentioned. Develop a plugin instead and have your users to install this plugin as a prerequisite to use your application.

Alternatively, here's a way you can try to instantiate an ActiveX object in your javascript BUT again this may well need IE settings to be manually set to allow ActiveX to be invoked or to run this javascript. You may need test this out.

```html
xx
```

```js
     try {
var shellObj = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
            var clsid = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-000000000000";
            var progid = shellObj.RegRead("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\CLSID\\{" + clsid + "}\\ProgID\\");
            var plugin = new ActiveXObject(progid);
            if (plugin) {
                //whatever you want to achieve
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }
}
```